What is the first vowel of "pardon" used as interjection?
I know that "pardon", when used as a normal word in a sentence, is pronounced /pɑːdn̩/, with a long vowel. But it seems to me that when used as an interjection to signal that you did not understand what another person said, the vowel is short. I think it sounds like "pudden" /p​ɐdn̩/*, but it could also but "padden" /p​adn̩/. A pronunciation with a short vowel is found neither in Cambridge dictionary nor in wiktionary, so I could be imagining things, but the "pardon" in "Pardon?" sounds very distinct from the pardon in "Pardon me!" to me.
See e.g. "pardon" https://youtu.be/IcR3sKZSFBM?t=239 at 3:58 vs "pardon me" https://youtu.be/g8tjdzvaeAQ?t=200 at 3:20.
So what is the vowel in "pardon"?
*: /pʌdn̩/, /pædn̩/ in "traditional" English IPA, which, to my knowledge, is outdated and does not match actual pronunciation anymore.
Edit: Since people seemingly find this hard to answer: Would saying "pudden" be off? If yes, this would be a fine answer.
Since the accent of the speaker might matter, see e.g. https://youtu.be/Q738qPOTzNE?t=535 and other examples in https://youglish.com/pronounce/pardon%3F/english/uk.
It does not occur in US examples, where it always has a audible "r", as expected.

I agree that it sounds unusual, but Romesh Ranganathan's accent is... unusual. I wouldn't regard it as an example of typical English speech.

@JavaLatte - Romesh Ranganathan's accent is... very typical Southern England middle class. A tiny bit London/estuary but not much at all. Not a bit unusual. He talks a bit posher than many people from Crawley New Town, West Sussex, where he was born in 1978. Before becoming a comedian he was a teacher in a town (Banstead, Surrey) where I had a cousin. Likewise the woman in the other clip, who says the word more or less the same way. To my ear, born south London, lived in Surrey, living in Bristol, he sounds exactly like I would expect.

And that accent carries over to Boston, Massachusetts. Also, said with intentional sarcasm, it might be said as, "Well! paahhdon me!"

I think we have a false premise here. The difference between the two pronunciations is simply because they are two different speakers. Any difference in the way you speak the two versions is in inflection and vocal pitch, not vowel.

I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misunderstanding.

@MichaelHarvey I agree, I come from a very similar background as you, SE London Worked in Wiltshire & Hampshire, retired to Oxfordshire, and his Accent, or lack of it sounds completely normal to me.

@AndyBonner : I would accept "No, it's definitely /ɑː/, and the reason it sounds different is entirely the vocal pitch." as answer, too.  The problem is that I hear no length. That it is not /ɑː/ is not part of the premise!

@Dodezv I'm still confused. The question seems to ask about vowel sound. Do you need to edit it? But more importantly, you got the idea that the way you use the word changes the way you say it, but it seems that you got that idea by listening to one person say "Pardon?" and a different person say "Pardon me?". I think that, for each speaker, the only difference between the two uses would be pitch. That's true of me, certainly.

@Andy Bonner No, I got the idea because I wanted to look up that word Brits say when they don't understand something. And did not know how to find it, because I never linked it with "pardon", which sounds different to me. The youtube links were illustrations.

Maybe you need to find an example of one person saying it the two different ways? It might be because I'm American that I'm skeptical about a difference, and it might be that this needs to be a question specifically about certain British accents.

Find a native English speaker and ask them to say it. I think I use the same vowel in both contexts, although it may be stressed differently and extended.

Your question appears to revolve around whether southern British English speakers would change pronunciation according to whether they are using 'pardon' as an interjection or other contexts. The answer is basically 'no'.
In your two examples, we're simply seeing the difference between somebody speaking very fast, and somebody speaking in a more leisurely (and presentational) manner.
Ranganathan is interjecting 'pardon' very quickly. In doing so he has reduced all the vowel sounds to almost nothing: 'p'dn?' Yes it does sound a bit like 'pudden', although I think it would usually be considered an unstressed 'schwa' sound (pәdәn).
The other speaker is simply taking more time to speak, and giving 'pardon' the usual southern English non-rhotic pronunciation: 'pah-dәn'.
If one said (as you have it) 'pudden' in a stressed or emphasized way, it would likely be considered to be strange. When speaking very fast, it is completely normal.
One could probably find examples of Ranganathan saying 'pah-don' in a much more elongated way, as an interjection, although I haven't tried to do so.
